# sprintf converts \n to space

Tags: r, printf, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to format a table in R with means and standard deviations. As part of the table generation, I pass the mean and sd to the following function:

```
mean_sd_string <- function(m,s){
    return(sprintf("%.2f\n(%.2f)",m,s))
}
```

I would expect that, e.g., `mean_sd_string(.3432,.1232)` would return

```
'.343
 (.123)'
```

But instead it returns

```
'.343 (.123)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it is for printing wrap it with `cat` i.e. `cat(mean_sd_string(.3432,.1232), sep="\n")`

Comment: On my system it returns `[1] "0.34\n(0.12)"` as expected.